# Python Delete Files in Directory from list in Text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've searched through many answers on deleting multiple files based on certain parameters (e.g. all txt files). Unfortunately, I haven't seen anything where one has a longish list of files saved to a .txt (or .csv) file and wants to use that list to delete files from the working directory.

I have my current working directory set to where the .txt file is (text file with list of files for deletion, one on each row) as well as the ~4000 .xlsx files. Of the xlsx files, there are ~3000 I want to delete (listed in the .txt file).

This is what I have done so far:

```
import os
path = "c:\\Users\\SFMe\\Desktop\\DeleteFolder"
os.chdir(path)
list = open('DeleteFiles.txt')
for f in list:
   os.remove(f)
```

This gives me the error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'Test1.xlsx\n'
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide the full path when you do os.remove

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Strip ending `'\n'` from each line read from the text file;
2. Make absolute path by joining `path` with the file name;
3. Do not overwrite Python types (i.e., in you case `list`);
4. Close the text file or use `with open('DeleteFiles.txt') as flist`.

EDIT: Actually, upon looking at your code, due to `os.chdir(path)`, second point may not be necessary.

---

```
import os
path = "c:\\Users\\SFMe\\Desktop\\DeleteFolder"
os.chdir(path)
flist = open('DeleteFiles.txt')
for f in flist:
    fname = f.rstrip() # or depending on situation: f.rstrip('\n')
    # or, if you get rid of os.chdir(path) above,
    # fname = os.path.join(path, f.rstrip())
    if os.path.isfile(fname): # this makes the code more robust
        os.remove(fname)

# also, don't forget to close the text file:
flist.close()
```

Comment: Changing my original 'os.remove(f)' for 'os.remove(os.path.join(path, f.strip()))' did the trick. And good reminder for not overwriting list. Thanks so much for help!

Answer (score 3):

As Henry Yik pointed in the commentary, you need to pass the full path when using `os.remove` function. Also, `open` function just returns the `file` object. You need to read the lines from the file. And don't forget to close the file. A solution would be:

```
import os
path = "c:\\Users\\SFMe\\Desktop\\DeleteFolder"
os.chdir(path)
# added the argument "r" to indicates only reading
list_file = open('DeleteFiles.txt', "r") 
# changing variable list to _list to do not shadow 
# the built-in function and type list
_list = list_file.read().splitlines() 
list_file.close()
for f in _list:
   os.remove(os.path.join(path,f))
```

A further improvement would be use list comprehension instead of a loop and a `with` block, which "automagically" closes the file for us:

```
with open('DeleteFiles.txt', "r") as list_file:
    _list = list_file.read().splitlines()
    [os.remove(os.path.join(path,f)) for f in _list]
```